# Find absolute minimum on domain with two inequalities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find the absolute minimum of

$$
f(x,y)=x^2+5xy+3y^2-4x-2y-5
$$

on the domain
$$-3\le x\le9, 1\le y\le10$$

I have attempted to find the boundaries with

$$f(-3,y)=3y^2-17y+16$$$$f'(-3,y)=6y-17=0$$$$y=17/6$$$$f(-3,17/6)=-225/4$$

but it seems this is not the correct answer. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: Trying to find critical points in the interior
$$2x+5y-4=0$$$$6y+5x-2=0$$$$x=-14/13,y=16/13$$$$f(-14/13,16/13)=-2225/169$$which is still incorrect.

Trying with x=9 $$f(9,y)=43y+3y^2+40$$$$f'(9,y)=6y+43=0$$$$y=-43/6$$
which I am confused about why this does not fit in the constraint inequality?

Calculating f(x,1) I end up with $$f(x,y)=-41/4$$
For f(x,10) I get -23 which again does not work with the constraint.

The corners are as follows:$$f(-3,1)=-4$$$$f(-3,10)=-454$$$$f(9,1)=80$$$$f(9,10)=170$$

however none of these are working for me as the correct minimum?

Comment: also check critical points in the interior

Comment: Actually you're on the right track by computing the value of $f$ on boundaries first. Then derive $f$ with respect to each parameters $x$ and $y$ and compare the minima you find in the interior of the domain with the value on the boundary. Conclude

Comment: you also need the $y$  endpoints, and the four corners

Comment: also $f(x,1) $ and $f(x,10)$  and $f(-3,1), f(-3,10), f(9,1), f(9,10)$

Comment: @WillJagy I updated my question with those values, but it is still not working for me?

Comment: do all four corners again.

Comment: You can try the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker method][1]. I think you got the right minimum, $(-3,17/6)$ but the minimum value should be $-97/12$


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions